# Show a progress bar while a function runs in a loop until it returns a value

Tags: vb.net

I have a function that runs an sql query for data that may or may not be there. Since I need to run this function continually until it returns the proper value how can I run a progress bar until the loop finishes.

```
status = Logic.ProcessResource(currentInstance)
While status.woID.Count <= 0
     status = Logic.ProcessResource(currentInstance)
End While
```

How can I run this and show another form with a progress bar until the loop exits?

Comment: Put that code into a different **thread**, then use a ProgressBar in "Marquee" mode to indicate an operation that is ongoing, but has no known ending time.

Comment: can I show the progress bar in a different form?

Comment: Yes...but you still need to put the query/loop in a different thread...otherwise the main UI thread will to be to busy to animate and remain responsive to the user.

Comment: Look at the BackgroundWorker control, or using a Task, with Async/Await.

Comment: So I code the large task into the background worker, have the worker show the form and when its complete close the form?

Comment: You'd show the form, start the worker, wait for worker to finish, then close the form.  The BackgroundWorker() has UI friendly **events** like `RunWorkerCompleted` that are already marshaled to the UI thread for you.

Comment: Looks like it's working, the form with the bar opens and the taskbar runs, I'll have to insert data into the DB and see if it closes now.

Comment: @Idle_Mind if you want to post that as the answer I'll mark it

Comment: also, you may need Control.Invoke and friend functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comments as an answer...

Put that code into a different thread, then use a ProgressBar in "Marquee" mode to indicate an operation that is ongoing, but has no known ending time.

Yes...but you still need to put the query/loop in a different thread...otherwise the main UI thread will to be to busy to animate and remain responsive to the user.

Look at the BackgroundWorker control, or using a Task, with Async/Await.

You'd show the form, start the worker, wait for worker to finish, then close the form. The BackgroundWorker() has UI friendly events like RunWorkerCompleted that are already marshaled to the UI thread for you.